# Subaru Forester Power Tailgate won't open

Tags: subaru, body, forester

When I press the power tailgate button to open the tailgate, it beeps 3 times quickly (and does not open).  Same behavior when trying to close the gate using the button on the bottom (3 beeps, doesn't close)

Workaround is to press the release for a few seconds triggering the manual opening of the gate, or just to close it myself.  Kind of frustrating however.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From a [technical service bulletin](http://www.subaruforester.org/vbulletin/attachments/f88/116569d1388373095-2014-forester-trunk-hatch-randomly-stops-working-powergatetsb.pdf) regarding the 2014 Subaru's:

> If you receive a customer concern of a “beep- beep-beep” sound when
>   trying to operate the PRG, a likely cause is an incomplete
>   initialization procedure.

Repair Procedure:

> 1. With the ignition “OFF”, open the PRG manually using a fluid motion (no light flash or beep should occur).
> 2. Carefully (slowly) close the rear gate until the first audible “click” of the rear gate latch mechanism is heard then immediately let
>      go of the rear gate. The auto closer function will then operate to
>      complete the rear gate closing / latching function. This will also
>      complete the initialization process. If the auto closer function is
>      inoperative, diagnose per the applicable Service Manual.
> 3. After the PRG is fully closed, operate either the Gate Opener switch, the Gate Inner (close) switch, remote keyless access switch or
>      the Interior PRG Open/Close switch to verify the automatic opening and
>      closing operation.
> 4. If the PRG inoperative condition persists, record the radio station presets (and navigation system favorites, if applicable).
> 5. IMPORTANT: Record any codes currently in PRG memory as the next step will clear them. 6. Disconnect the positive and negative cables
>      from the vehicle’s battery, touch the 2 cable ends together creating a
>      capacitive discharge which will clear the memory.
> 6. Reconnect the cables to the battery, reset all radio presets (and navigation favorites, if applicable) then confirm normal PRG
>      operation. • If the customer’s PRG usage pattern precludes the ability
>      of the system to initialize upon closing, and control unit replacement
>      is determined to be necessary to assure customer satisfaction, order
>      and replace the PRG control unit following the service procedure
>      outlined in the applicable Service Manual. • If the PRG still does not
>      operate properly, utilize any codes pulled from the system and follow
>      the rest of the diagnostic procedures beginning on page PRG(diag)-2 of
>      the 2014 Forester Service Manual.

Comment: Removing the negative battery lead and touching it to the positive battery terminal reset the PRG as described. However now the PRG will only open about 15% and stays there. Ugh.

Comment: Update:  In regards to my second issue (PRG only opening about 15%) had to do with a feature I wasn't aware of... There is a button to the left of and below the steering wheel that can be toggled that tells the PRG to use the "Preset" height to open (used for small garages), and the default is an unusable 15%... had to make sure that button was untoggled.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem affected my 2014 Forester XT.  I followed Badpirate's advise except that I didn't short the two terminals: taking the positive lead off is too much work.  I removed the negative lead and left it unplugged for 5 min.  This had the same effect of resetting the PRG without losing all my radio station presets.  The liftgate now opens using the keyfob or inside button.

Answer (score 0):

My 2016 Forester power rear gate stopped d working with the fob button and the interior button..  The solution my dealer came up with was to reset the solenoid which he did by locking and unlocking the power door buttons on the driver door several times in a row.  Problem was solved.